# Camera Capture Without Preview in Android 2.2

Tags: android

I have a requirement to Capture the image without showing the Preview..
And i want to do it in the Background as a Service.

Is it possible to do that??

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to achieve. 
You should define a class that handles the Camera object, as in calls on Camera.open() and such.
Don't provide the camera object with the following lines in order to disable the preview -

```
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mTargetHolder);
```

Where `mTargetHolder` is the SurfaceView.

If you want to receive frame callbacks you can implement the Camera.PreviewCallback interface.

Now before you call on camera.startPreview() register you callback handler using setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(Camera.PreviewCallback). [Camera reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

With this frame data you receive from the callback you can do what ever you want. just remember that it is a raw data format.
See also Camera.PictureCallback usage if you wish to take a picture.

I hope this helps. (even if not relevant)

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure that the picture will be taken without a call to `setPreviewDisplay`? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: removing this line, doesn't show the preview on the surface, but it still needs a surface, attached to the main window, to work.. so now instead of a preview, i can get a black surface :) do you maybe know of any way to work around this?

Comment: To make it work on every device, surface must be added somewhere and actually created. See comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview