# Capture picture from front camera and save it on SD card without preview

Tags: android, camera

How can i capture a picture from front camera without preview and save it to SD card.
Kindly help me with source code.

Comment: have a look here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601928/camera-capture-without-preview-in-android-2-2 even if it is not relevant it will help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Camera without Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 public void takePictureNoPreview(Context context){
          // open back facing camera by default
          Camera myCamera=Camera.open();

          if(myCamera!=null){
            try{
              //set camera parameters if you want to
              //...

              // here, the unused surface view and holder
              SurfaceView dummy=new SurfaceView(context)
              myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(dummy.getHolder());    
              myCamera.startPreview(); 

              myCamera.takePicture(null, null, getJpegCallback()):

            }finally{
              myCamera.close();
            }      

          }else{
            //booo, failed!
          }


          private PictureCallback getJpegCallback(){
            PictureCallback jpeg=new PictureCallback() {   
              @Override
              public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream fos;
                try {
                  fos = new FileOutputStream("test.jpeg");
                  fos.write(data);
                  fos.close();
                }  catch (IOException e) {
                  //do something about it
                }
              }
            };
          }
        }
```

Comment: @city0666 , it points errors to myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(dummy.getHolder());  
and  private PictureCallback getJpegCallback() {

Comment: To make it work on every device, surface must be added somewhere and actually created.  See comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview

Answer (score -1):

Not possible, however, there's work-arounds.

See this previous answer, and please, try searching before asking in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3881027/181002

Comment: Nothing is impossible bro... Check this out   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744790/android-possible-to-camera-capture-without-a-preview