# Android: How to capture image without showing preview

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent, image-capture

I am using the following code to capture the image in Android

`Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 100);`

After capturing an image, its showing a preview and asking whether to save or discard the image.

Is there anyway where i can avoid this preview?

The Camera app in Android dosent shows the preview. So there should be a way i guess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744790/android-possible-to-camera-capture-without-a-preview

Comment: please provide the solution i am facing the same problem I also dnt want the preview screen to come after the photo clicked

Answer (score 2):

The camera app doesn't give other apps the option to disable the confirmation screen, even though the camera app itself doesn't show the confirmation screen.

Therefore it is not possible for not showing the confirmation screen.

However we can achieve this by writing a custom app using the Camera library in android. (see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744790/android-possible-to-camera-capture-without-a-preview))

Comment: This is so sad. Why can't they leave us some choices? If you want the user to be able to use all camera effects and settings you can't just write your own camera capturing activity with all these features.