# How to record 720p videos without dropping frames in Android

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk, h.264, video-recording

I compiled ffmpeg and h264 libraries for android using NDK. 
I am recording videos using the [muxing.c](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.2/muxing_8c-example.html) example from the ffmpeg library. Everything works correct (still haven't worked on the audio) but the camera is dropping frames and it takes around 100ms to save each frame, which is unacceptable.

I have also tried making a queue and saving them into another thread (let's call it B) but at the end I need to wait for around 120 seconds because the background thread (B)is still recording the frames.

Is there a workaround for this issue, besides reducing the video size? Ideally I would like to save the frames in real time, at least reduce the saving time. Is it just that Android is incapable of doing this? .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, check if you can be better served by the hardware encoder (via MediaRecorder or MediaCodec in Java, or using OpenMax from native code).

If for some reason you *must* encode in software, and your device is multicore, you can gain a lot by compiling x264 to use sliced multithreading. Let me [cite my post of 2 years ago](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/pc3-C-SYeCw):

> We are using x264 directly (no ffmpeg code involved), and with ultafast/zerolatency preset we get 30 FPS for VGA on Samsung Note10 (http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_10_1_n8000-4573.php) with Quad-core 1.4 GHz Cortex-A9 Exynos 4412 CPU, which is on the paper weaker than Droid's Quad-core 1.5 GHz Krait Qualcomm MDM615m/APQ8064 (http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_droid_dna-5113.php).
>
> Note that x264 build scripts do not enable pthreads for Android (because NDK does not include libpthread.a), bit you can build the library with multithread support (very nice for a Quad-core CPU) if you simply create a dummy libpthread.a, see https://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/x264-devel/2013-March/009941.html.

Note that encoder setup is only one part of the problem. If you work with the *deprecated* camera API, you should use preallocated buffers and a background thread for camera callbacks, as I explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23687111/192373).

Comment: I will be trying this. I forgot to say that MediaRecorder takes too much time to start recording. I would like to have the "press and record" functionality, similar to vine. I haven't tried OpenMax, does it take similar time to start recording as MediaRecorder?. Thank you.

Comment: I believe that MediaCodec and OpenMax approaches don't involve any significant delay.