# Recording video from a Service

Tags: android, android-camera, android-service, video-capture, preview

I'm sorry if there's a duplicate, however I wasn't able to find a clear answer after some time of searching. Is it still impossible to capture video without a preview? Is it possible to implement this functionality without using any weird workarounds and to be sure that it should work on most of devices. My requirement is to make a spy function that will record the video without the user seeing it. Is it feasible? If not - then how do apps like Secret Video Recording work? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview and this one shows an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744790/android-possible-to-camera-capture-without-a-preview

Comment: @dnxviral, Thanks, although, it looks like the implementation isn't very stable and is likely to fail on some devices..