# android - use camera from within background service

Tags: android, service, background, camera

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to use a camera video stream from within a background **service** rather than from a normal intent.

What I had in mind is this:

- start the service from my app
- this service accesses the video stream and extracts features continuously; depending on the features, it sends network packets (to localhost)
- user switches to another app - *the service must still be running and extracting features!*

Before trying to implement all that, I'd like to know if it was possible.

Thanks in advance

Nicola

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible as the camera needs a preview screen. See previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview)

Comment: i guess you're right; i found this interesting discussion of the topic: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9570

Answer (score 3):

yes its possible, check my answer and sample code on one similar thread

[Open/Run Camera from background service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976614/open-run-camera-from-background-service-in-android/14997460)

Comment: your method is working ONLY if you open activity firstly - to initialize surfaceview, then use it in service

Answer (score 1):

You have to show the fake preview over the current screen. For that you have to create the surface view with 1*1 px dimension and display the preview in that. You have to draw the surface view over other apps for that.

**Check out [this](https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-hidden-camera) library that provides facility to capture image from the background even from the service.**

Comment: While Trying to use this library i am getting Camera error. Unable to open camera or something. Please suggest what should i do.