# Open/Run Camera from background service in android

Tags: android

Want to build an app which keeps recording in background, is it possible ?

Comment: well i'm not sure about that, but what i know is that u can use the recording method on the onPause() method so when your is on the background will keep recording. and btw what have you tried ?

Comment: think it is possible and u hav done the same what if another app or default camera app requests for camera? it will show camera already in use ?? doesnt it seam spying is not a good habit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

yes its very well possible.

Create an activity which will start your background service on some event or you can also use alarm manager to start and stop the service as per your requirement.

Check some rough code which will start & stop recording using camera, this you can call from your background service and will work smoothly.

```
    public boolean starMediaRecording(){
            Camera.Parameters params = mServiceCamera.getParameters();
            mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
            Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

            final List<Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);
            p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
            mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);

            try {
                mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
                mServiceCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mServiceCamera.unlock();

            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/filenamevideo.mp4");
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mMediaRecorder.start(); 

            mRecordingStatus = true;

            return true;

    }

    public void stopMediaRecorder() {
        mServiceCamera.reconnect();

        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();

        mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
        mMediaRecorder.release();

        mServiceCamera.release();
        mServiceCamera = null;
    }
}
```

This is sample code, you need to add your own logic around and also handle exceptions accordingly.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I tried this and it worked after some minor changes.

Comment: what is mSurfaceHolder in your example ? If I'm using a empty one i get error on some device, and i cant really get one if i'm only using a service

Comment: This code works fine on Android 2.3.3 HTC Desire, but background recording fails on Galaxy S3 and Nexus 4. Any ideas?

Comment: Ditto on the mSurfaceHolder. That's my main problem, figuring out where to get that in a Service.

Comment: what is "mServiceCamera" in this method? DraD can you please tell me what changes you have done exactly?

Comment: What's the point of getting the camera parameters only to set them and get them again?

Comment: @Pawan M , what is the type of `mRecordingStatus` in the code?

Comment: First two commands in function `starMediaRecording` is useless right?

Comment: and you need `mServiceCamera.open(0)` at the very beginning.