# How to make an app run in background to do some task mention below?

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which calculates screen to face distance which has one camera preview in which app detect the eyes and calculates the distance and show distance above the preview and adjust the android system font according to distance calculated.
Currently the app calculates distance when i run it.
I want this app to continuously calculate the distance in background and change the font accordingly but now its not calculating distance in background.

I expect that app should not pause in background and calculate the distance even in background and change the system font accordingly.

Comment: Have you looked into using foreground services?

Comment: No,will try using this but i am using camera preview in that activity and then calculating distance so is it possible to do this using foreground service?

Comment: Yes it is possible. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1916653/9968399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WorkManager. WorkManager is best for background jobs. Refer following links

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager  (Introduction)

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/WorkManagerSample   (Examaple)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a typical example of a task you want to do in a background **Service**. To quote the description from [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Service):

> A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) and you can achieve this by using its core methods like **doInBackground** and **progressUpdate()**

Comment: But i am using camera preview in that activity and then calculating distance so is it possible to do this using service and if yes then could u please share any example related to this

Answer (score 0):

Just like what @FreddaP said, for me, I would use a `Service` in here because it seems like it only needs to go a single task, which is calculating the distance of the phone from a face, over and over again.

If you want to be a bit adventurous, use native code to increase it's speed (not like I know how to make it work though).

This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139133/5887056) seems to be what you'll need. Sorry I haven't used the camera before in my apps.

Comment: But i am using camera preview in that activity and then calculating distance so is it possible to do this using service and if yes then could u please share any example related to this

Answer (score 0):

I think that this particular problem (to use the camera without preview) has already been addressed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081052/can-i-use-android-camera-in-service-without-preview)