# How to use Camera to take picture in a background Service on Android?

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm developing a Service, running in background, that uploads succesfully images and data to the web.

Now I want to upload an image taken by the Camera.

Is it possible to use the camera in a background service without preview on Android 2.2?

I found various contrastants answers on web...

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can take pictures without preview with an dummy view.

like:

```
SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);
c.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
c.startPreview();
c.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawPictureCallback, jpegPictureCallback);
```

Comment: This doesn't work on all devices, as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5384913/318870

Comment: what is c,shutterCallback and all the variables..please provide the whole code

Comment: This code isn't correct. I needed to add the `view` to the `WindowManager`. I also needed to add a callback to `view.getHolder()` and then in `surfaceCreated` set the preview, start the preview, and take the picture.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without the preview / surface view.

Comment: True, but you can still use tricks such as a transparent preview or a 1x1 preview. Also, on some phones you can apparently use a dummy `SurfaceTexture` or `SurfaceView` that isn't displayed.

Comment: It works without the Surfaceview on some devices (like My note 2) but doesn't work on every device.
So it's a must to use SurfaceView.