# Android Camera - Running in background from service

Tags: android, service, camera, android-camera, android-service

I have been trying to run camera in background of a service. I have followed the method shown in [How to use Camera to take picture in a background Service on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398897/how-to-use-camera-to-take-picture-in-a-background-service-on-android) , [Taking picture from camera without preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview). This is what I have done

ExperimentalControl.java

```
package com.example.test2;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class ExperimentControl extends Service 
{
     VideoRecorder vRecorder;   

     public ExperimentControl() 
     {
         Log.i("EXPERIMENT","ExperimentControl started!!!");
     }

     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
     {
         return null;
     }

     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
     {

        vRecorder = new VideoRecorder();
        vRecorder.startRecording(getApplicationContext());

        return START_STICKY;
     }

     public void onDestroy()
     {
        vRecorder=null;
     }

}
```

VideoRecorder.java

```
package com.example.test2;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class VideoRecorder implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{
    String videofolder = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Record/";
    private final String VIDEO_PATH_NAME = videofolder+"test.mp4";
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private boolean mInitSuccesful;

    void startRecording(Context context)
    {
        Log.v("Surya2","here");
        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mMediaRecorder.start();
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //finish();
        Log.v("Surya4","here");
    }

    private void initRecorder(Surface surface) throws IOException 
    {

        if(mCamera == null) 
        {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.unlock();
        }

        if(mMediaRecorder == null) 
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(VIDEO_PATH_NAME);

        try 
        {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } 
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mInitSuccesful = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Log.v("Surya3","here");

            if(!mInitSuccesful)
                initRecorder(mHolder.getSurface());
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

    private void shutdown() 
    {
        // Release MediaRecorder and especially the Camera as it's a shared
        // object that can be used by other applications
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        mMediaRecorder.release();
        mCamera.release();

        // once the objects have been released they can't be reused
        mMediaRecorder = null;
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test2"
    android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service android:name=".ExperimentControl" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Is this way correct? And the main problem I am facing is this doesnot show any error nor log ouput is coming.So I am unable to get to identify what is causing the problem but the video is not recorded. Can anybody please correct me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Service context to call startrecording

```
vRecorder.startRecording(this);
```

You should avoid using ApplicationContext to create views. I got similar problem when i tried to create AlertDialog based on ApplicationContext. No errors were shown but dialog was now shown.

Hopes it helps!