# Take a photo automatically without user interaction

Tags: android, camera, android-camera-intent

I used this code to capture an image from the camera.

```
package android.takeowneship;


import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class camera extends Activity{


    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    Uri imageUri;
    private ImageView imageView;

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

          //define the file-name to save photo taken by Camera activity
            String fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";
            //create parameters for Intent with filename
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image capture by camera");
            //imageUri is the current activity attribute, define and save it for later usage (also in onSaveInstanceState)
            imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            //create new Intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        }

     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

         if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 //use imageUri here to access the image
                 Toast.makeText(this, "picture has been taken"+ imageUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


             } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             } else {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         }

         }

     public static File convertImageUriToFile (Uri imageUri, Activity activity)  {

         Cursor cursor = null;
         try {
             String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
             cursor = activity.managedQuery( imageUri,
                     proj, // Which columns to return
                     null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                     null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                     null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
             int file_ColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
//           int orientation_ColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION);
             if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
//               String orientation =  cursor.getString(orientation_ColumnIndex);
                 return new File(cursor.getString(file_ColumnIndex));
             }
             return null;
         } finally {
             if (cursor != null) {
                 cursor.close();
             }
         }
         }
```

}

But in this code it opens the camera and user has to click the button to take the photo.
What I want is to take the photo automatically (without a preview) and saves it in the memory card.

Comment: Have you considered that this is actually a security measurement? Why do you think this is possible at all? Also, why do you need that?

Comment: On a positive note, if you do find a way, I'll have to file a bug report somewhere :-)

Comment: I'm building a security application.
So I need to take the photograph without knowing the user.

Comment: I hope it can't be done!

Answer (score 13):

Android does not allow you to take picture without showing the preview window. So you have to make the surface view very small. Like **1*1 pixel and put it in a corner** of any control.

Or show a dummy surface view to do this.

```
SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);
c.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
c.startPreview();
c.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawPictureCallback, jpegPictureCallback);
```

Check *(broken link removed)*, [this](http://droidcoders.blogspot.sg/2011/09/android-taking-pictures-without-preview.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview) out.

Comment: For my case, I need to say `c.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));`, `c.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());` would throw RuntimeException

Answer (score 4):

This code is capturing an image using the front camera and save it automatically

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    int index = getFrontCameraId();
    if (index == -1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No front camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
         iv_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);   
         sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);  
         sHolder = sv.getHolder();  
         sHolder.addCallback(this);  
         sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);  
    }
}   

@Override  
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h)  
{  
     parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
     mCamera.setParameters(parameters);  
     mCamera.startPreview();  

     Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback()  
     {  
         @Override  
         public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)  
         {          
            Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert//(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, image);
            (Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());

             OutputStream imageFileOS;
             try {
                 imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
                 imageFileOS.write(data);
                 imageFileOS.flush();
                 imageFileOS.close();

                 Toast.makeText(TakePictureActivity.this,
                         "Image saved: " + uriTarget.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
             catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             //mCamera.startPreview();

             bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);  
             iv_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);  
         }  
     };  

     mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
}  

int getFrontCameraId() {
    CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
        if (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) return i;
        }
return -1; // No front-facing camera found
}

@Override  
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)  
 {
    int index = getFrontCameraId();
    if (index == -1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No front camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        mCamera = Camera.open(index);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "With front camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
      mCamera = Camera.open(index);  
      try {  
         mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);  

      } catch (IOException exception) {  
          mCamera.release();  
          mCamera = null;  
      }  

 }

@Override  
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)  
{  
    mCamera.stopPreview();  
    mCamera.release();  
    mCamera = null;  
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**Description**

I would like to take picture with without confirmation button on Android.

**Solution**

Use *"android.intent.extra.quickCapture"*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.quickCapture",true);
```

Comment: This has been [sealed recently](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2019/11/google-samsung-fix-android-spying-flaw-other-makers-may-still-be-vulnerable/), hasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Capturing Image without user interaction(without user action) and capture an image in background using android service 


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CapPhoto extends Service
{
    private SurfaceHolder sHolder;  
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Parameters parameters;


  @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
      super.onCreate();
      Log.d("CAM", "start");

      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
               new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);};
          Thread myThread = null;


  }
  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    super.onStart(intent, startId);

 if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() >= 2) {

    mCamera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT); }

 if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() < 2) {

    mCamera = Camera.open(); }
    SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());


     try {
               mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
               parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
               mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
               mCamera.startPreview();

               mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
         } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        sHolder = sv.getHolder();
        sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
  }

  Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback()
  {

     public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera)
     {

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try{

                    File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "A");
                    if(!sd.exists()) {                               
                      sd.mkdirs();
                      Log.i("FO", "folder" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                    }

                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
                        String tar = (sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(sd+tar+".jpg");
                        outStream.write(data);  outStream.close();

                        Log.i("CAM", data.length + " byte written to:"+sd+tar+".jpg");
                        camkapa(sHolder);             


                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    Log.d("CAM", e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e){
                    Log.d("CAM", e.getMessage());
                }}
  };


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
          return null;
    }

    public void camkapa(SurfaceHolder sHolder) {

        if (null == mCamera)
            return;
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
        Log.i("CAM", " closed");
        }

    }



 Step:2 Activity File - name is :Second.java





import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Second extends Activity {


    Intent service;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        service = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CapPhoto.class);
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 15);
        //TAKE PHOTO EVERY 15 SECONDS
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, service, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                     60*60*1000, pintent);
        startService(service);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }


}


step 3: Android manife

st file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dbsource.dbinsert"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Second"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <service android:name=".CapPhoto" android:enabled="true">

                   <intent-filter>

                    </intent-filter>
                </service>

        </application>



</manifest>


refer this link [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://chandandroid.blogspot.in/2014/04/capturing-image-without-user-action.html
```