# Android take picture withoud preview

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, surfaceholder

Do you know a way to take a picture without previewing? I searched and found only non-working solutions like setting the surface view width and height to 1 dp.

Comment: I am currently working on similar issue. Have you read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html ?

Comment: As I see the guide is only for a surfaceview that is previewed.

Comment: possible duplicate of _[Take Picture without preview android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799976/take-picture-without-preview-android)_ and _[Android Camera without Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview)_

Answer (score 0):

You can choose not to call the following function to prevent a preview from showing.

```
Camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder)
```

Comment: Will the camera work without being previewed? I thought Android requires a preview to use the camera.

Comment: I tested it with an app I'm developing now (it uses the camera as a barcode scanner) and I was able to take the picture no problem.

Comment: which api did u used? will it work after android 4?

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow (it's pretty late here). If it works I'll mark your answer as correct. Thank you :)

Comment: It works on the emulator but crashed when I run it on a real device. I tried it on sony xperia M