# how can i implement the camera program without preview?

Tags: android, background, camera

how can i implement the camera program without preview?
(like Gallaxy S3's Smart Stay & Smart rotation)

Even if the other app is running in foreground, my camera program must be running in background.

is it possible??
if you know, help me, please. (source, guide, method...)

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Camera without Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview)

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is not possible with standart means,  as android camera api requires  working preview  and surface view -  samsung applications are free to use native and undocumented features you do not know about.

However, api documentation says that there shall be surface view  but nobody says it shall be visible - you can put overlay over it, or make it 1x1 px somewhere in the far corner

Comment: i've had my own problems with trying to hide the preview surface for the camera. it seems like it can only take the picture when it's being previewed from the surfaceview - something like that. if it's to limit developers from building apps that can "spy" on users, i'm not sure, but it's definitely something the oem can work around with - Samsung did.

Comment: You can add a SurfaceView to the system WindowManager with a 1x1 size so it's invisible and attach the preview to this surface. Just make sure to do all the camera functions on the onSurfaceCreated callback.

Answer (score 0):

You have to show the fake preview over the current screen. For that you have to create the surface view with 1*1 px dimension and display the preview in that.

Check out [this](https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-hidden-camera) library that provides facility to capture image from background.