# Android: Is it possible to take a picture with the camera from a service with no UI

Tags: android, camera

The only code I have been able to get working to take a picture with the camera runs from an activity. I am fairly certain that it is possible to take a photo from within a service, or from an AsyncTask launched by the service.

It seems to me that the camera API needs a SurfaceView which must be tied into a UI. Maybe I am wrong. Has anyone written code where a photo can be taken from a service?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible as the camera needs a preview screen. See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview)

Comment: It is possible to do it with *effectively* no preview, as shown in the question you linked.

Comment: @Gridtestmail then how the app taking picture without user knowledge? . They started a service to take picture and using dummy surface view/ Surface texture . https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zenaapps.backgroundcamera . How can we achieve the same ? could  you provide any code sample , if you have any?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible by using `WindowManager` in Android.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10268650/3047840

I should say yes you need `SurfaceView` to take a picture but it does not have to be tied to a certain xml layout. You can add it to the `WindowManager` class which works even in the Service. So the `WindowManager` here opens a 'window' for you to do any floating effect in Android.

Specifically,

You can add a `SurfaceView` into the `WindowManager` and set the parameters as following.

```
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, jpegCallback);
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

params.height = 1;
params.width = 1;

wm.addView(mPreview, params);
```

Android has this functionality while iOS doesn't. This is why you can have Facebook chathead active on the home screen in Android rather than iOS.

[Show facebook like chat head from a broadcast receiver in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19033426/3047840)

Comment: It's important to note that this method requires the android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission, which users may take issue with.

Comment: This worked for me, although your code sample is missing some essential parts.

Comment: @Sam care to add the missing essential parts?

Comment: @Ben, I can't remember what they were. But see my answer to the original question for a complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27083867/238753

Answer (score 3):

Here's some more complete code if you are still looking.  Works in a service (tested):

```
private void takePhoto() {

    System.out.println( "Preparing to take photo");
    Camera camera = null;

    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);

        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);

            try {
                camera = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                System.out.println("Camera not available: " + camIdx);
                camera = null;
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try{
            if (null == camera) {
                System.out.println("Could not get camera instance");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Got the camera, creating the dummy surface texture");
                //SurfaceTexture dummySurfaceTextureF = new SurfaceTexture(0);
                try {
                    //camera.setPreviewTexture(dummySurfaceTextureF);
                    camera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
                    camera.startPreview();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Could not set the surface preview texture");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        File pictureFileDir = getDir();
                        if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
                        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                        String photoFile = "PictureFront_" + "_" + date + ".jpg";
                        String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;
                        File mainPicture = new File(filename);
                        addImageFile(mainPicture);

                        try {
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mainPicture);
                            fos.write(data);
                            fos.close();
                            System.out.println("image saved");
                        } catch (Exception error) {
                            System.out.println("Image could not be saved");
                        }
                        camera.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            camera.release();
        }


    }
```

Comment: From my experiments, the dummy `SurfaceTexture` workaround worked on Nexus 4 and HTC One m8 but it failed on Nexus 5 :(

Comment: What was the issue you were getting while trying in Nexus 5?

Comment: This doesn't work on my Sony Xperia M running Android 4.3 because of the dummy `SurfaceTexture` technique.