# takePicture in service not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to take a picture with the back camera and then get it's bytes in a serice I am using this code:

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
SurfaceHolder holder = view.getHolder();
camera.getParameters().setPreviewSize(1, 1);
camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
camera.startPreview();
camera.takePicture(null, pictureCallback, null);
```

But it is not working. I am not getting an exception but pictureCallback is never being called.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the android docs: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

You should call the camera intent like this:

First add the necessary permissions to your app in the androidmanifest file:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

After that call the corresponding intent to start the camera:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

The data you receive from the camera will be called in the following method, where you will be able to store or use it as you wish:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

In case you want to implement this in a service, taking the code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277981/android-is-it-possible-to-take-a-picture-with-the-camera-from-a-service-with-no), you should be able to take a picture from a service:

```
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, jpegCallback);
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

params.height = 1;
params.width = 1;

wm.addView(mPreview, params);
```

As stated by the comments, please note that this needs the permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW to work, users might not want to allow an App to use this permission.

Comment: I said in a service I can't use that code in a service.