# IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died

Tags: android, android-camera, audio-recording

recently i came across this question but have no clue. I want to use "mediarecorder" record 720P video stream and send it to server in realtime. Here is my code:

```
try{
    soc = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(hostname), port);
} catch (UnknownHostException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
CamcorderProfile pProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
//pProfile.videoFrameWidth = 1280;
//pProfile.videoFrameWidth = 720;
recorder.setProfile(pProfile);

//recorder.setOutputFile(myRecAudioFile.getAbsolutePath());//保存路径

pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(soc);
recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

the android API level is 17, when i start the media recorder, the program will die just one or two seconds . The error log like this :

```
IMediaDeathNotifier- media server died
Camera  -  Camera server died
```

Can anybody who have came across the similar question give me some advice?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set a preview display for your `MediaRecorder`:

```
SurfaceView mySurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.my_surface_view);
Surface mySurface = camera.getHolder().getSurface();
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(mySurface);
```

Apparently android does not allow you to play video unless you have set a preview display surface [(ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview).