# Android - How to record video without preview?

Tags: android, camera, video-capture

I'm writing an app which uses multiple layouts. How to record video in background without having visible SurfaceView and despite changing layouts (with `setContentView()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SurfaceView of size 1x1 pixels, it should work on most devices.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386025/2203164) for more answers.

Comment: Especially useful may be the last one, about the way to set up media recorder without preview