# Take a photo using a service on OnePlus One - using WindowManager hack

Tags: android, android-camera, oneplusone

I'm trying to take a picture without showing the user anything (no view) through a service. This question has been asked several times before and I've gone through all I could find. Some similar questions:

- [Android Camera.takePicture failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441484/android-camera-takepicture-failed)
- [Android camera fails to take photo from background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463796/android-camera-fails-to-take-photo-from-background-service)

Most of the questions link to other questions without providing a new solution.

I believe this is the best way to solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10268650/3860594
Unfortunately the person has not provided a complete answer and I'm having trouble reproducing his method.

What I'm trying to do is create a SurfaceView inside a SurfaceHolder. I will then use WindowManager with the SurfaceView to create a floating window of sorts that is completely transparent so that it's hidden from the user. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is my code:

```
SurfaceView mview = new SurfaceView(this);
SurfaceHolder mholder = new SurfaceHolder() {
    @Override
    public void addCallback(Callback callback) {

    }

    @Override
    public void removeCallback(Callback callback) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCreating() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setType(int type) {

    }

    @Override
        public void setFixedSize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setSizeFromLayout() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setFormat(int format) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setKeepScreenOn(boolean screenOn) {
    }

    @Override
    public Canvas lockCanvas() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Canvas lockCanvas(Rect dirty) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
        public void unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas canvas) {

    }

    @Override
    public Rect getSurfaceFrame() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Surface getSurface() {
        return null;
    }
};


WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
wm.addView(mview, params);
mview.setZOrderOnTop(true);
mholder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);


try {
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(mview.getHolder());
    camera.startPreview();
    camera.takePicture(null,null,photoCallback);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

None of this works as the usual message `RuntimeException: takePicture failed` is shown. Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: Try to set the window not fully transparent and check if it really shows the preview on screen.

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks for your suggestion man, I tried setting it to opaque but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: The question was, do you see camera stream there?

Comment: @AlexCohn No, app launches and then crashes immediately with no floating windows or view finders.

Comment: Wait a sec, you saw `takePicture failed` before. Isn't this crash different?

Comment: Nope, this crash looked exactly the same, both on the phone, as well as the error on AStudio.

Comment: BTW, it is not clear what its the role of **mholder** field in your code snippet.

Comment: My bad: I didn't notice this mistake before. You should never call takePicture() immediately after addView(). You must wait at least for the `surfaceCreated()` callback.

Comment: `mholder` is only used in this code snippet in my application. It seems, mholder is actually not doing anything useful at all :/ Also, how can I wait for the surface created callback? (google search didn't help) thanks

Comment: mview.getHolder().addCallback()

Comment: I tried `SystemClock.sleep(20000);` right before `takePicture` and this time the phone screen turned black for a second right before the application crashed. Same error though.

Comment: Thanks, I added a callback and now there is no error and the app does not crash. However, the picture that was saved to storage was completely black.

Comment: The black screen is NOT an empty image (200kb size).. I think it's because the camera view is not loading properly, the captured image is black. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: is the preview also black?

Comment: There is no preview that appears on the screen (I tried both opaque and transparent), Logcat however, shows this warning: `I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 395 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.`

Comment: How do you open the camera?

Comment: I don't open the camera interface (if thats what you're asking), I want to directly take the picture without showing the user anything. As for how I open the `camera` object, you can see it in this screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/F5sXvgI.png

Comment: The choreographer message is expected, but maybe you can reduce the tasks that use the UI thread. But the second is strange: do you dispose the SurfaceView too early?

Comment: My project has a main activity, from which I start a service (onCreate), and I'm trying to run this method on the service. I'm not doing anything else on the UI. I did not dispose of SurfaceView anywhere. Maybe it's not created properly? Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe your mistake is that you create the SurfaceView in `onCreate()`. Try `onStart()` - it workes for me!

Comment: Sorry for the radio silence. Actually, my service is started on the onCreate of the main activity. And then my `takePicture` method is run from the `onStartCommand` method of the service. Perhaps you can upload your project as a zip for me to take a look? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/alexcohn/CameraInService

Comment: I really, really appreciate your code. But nowhere in CameraService.java do you call the `camera.takePicture` method to capture the image. The preview loads perfectly.

Comment: Add takePicture after preview is ready, see second commit.

Comment: I tried your code and it runs fine. To confirm the image gets captured accurately, I tried to save it to storage, and made the following modifications: https://gist.github.com/puckh/96769f8fddb53f542142#file-save-onpicturetaken-to-storage  and the picture gets saved as the familiar black screen.

Comment: sorry, works for me ;-) See the next commit. Actually, there is no reason except exercise to convert JPEG data to Bitmap and compress it back. You can save a PNG this way, though.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Very helpful. I tried everything, including just running your project, but my JPG is always just a black screen. I'm using a OnePlus One (API level 21).

Comment: @AlexCohn tried the code on a friends phone and it worked fine (couldn't get the preview to stay invisible but the picture came out unfocused and row res but still fine). Wonder why it didn't work on my phone. Thanks for the support. Really appreciate your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens so that the last brick in the puzzle was only revealed a week after the question was asked. The problem is specific to a particular device, namely, OnePlus One.

The sample code at https://github.com/alexcohn/CameraInService shows how this can be handled; the latest commit adds a delay between starting preview and performing **takePicture()**. The experiment on my wife's OnePlus One shows that delay of 100 ms is OK, but 1 ms is too short.