# Capture video without preview using Media Recorder

Tags: android, video, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying capture video (on lollipop) using [Media Recorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html), as I understand this class support capture without preview ([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video), #7 in the note):

> It is possible to use MediaRecorder without creating a camera preview
> first and skip the first few steps of this process. However, since
> users typically prefer to see a preview before starting a recording,
> that process is not discussed here.

So, I build app that start capture video automatically and stops by button clicking but I get exceptions any time, here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT); // Tried to put this line in comment 
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT); // Tried to put this line in comment 

    /*CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);*/

    recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyVideo.gpp");

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    recorder.start();

    final Button btnStopCaptureVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu_StopCapture);
    btnStopCaptureVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.reset();   // You can reuse the object by going back to setAudioSource() step
            recorder.release(); // Now the object cannot be reused
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Video create successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btnStopCaptureVideo.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
}
```

When the code is like below I got `RuntimeException` (on `recorder.start()` line) and one I comment `VideoEncoder` and `AudioEncoder` and un-comment `CamcorderProfile` I got `IllegalStateException` exception (on `recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile)` line).

So, the question is how can I capture Video without preview?